# Unclear as to the usage of async and await in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, expo

I've begun delving into using React Native with Expo recently on a side project. I wanted to load data asynchronously from Firebase and have achieved it after lots of attempts and googling but I still do not fully understand how it works.

```
 componentDidMount = async() => {
      await ref.once('value', async (snapshot) => {
      let imageUrl = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function(urlSnapshot) {
        imageUrl.push(urlSnapshot)
      });
      this.setState({ items : imageUrl});
    });
  }
```

In the following image, I understand I am telling componentDidMount to run asynchronously through the async() keyword. I also understand that the function is asking the function to await for the results of the once query but the one I am not understanding is the use of the async when calling the function to return the snapshot. There might be documentations or questions out there that show you how to do it but there isn't one to answer how it works which I would like to understand.

Comment: When adding code to a question on Stack Overflow, please don't show images of code.  Instead, copy the text of the code into the question itself and format it as code, so that it's easier to read and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson edited, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref.once()` ([link to API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once)) returns a promise that resolves when the database query is complete.  You can also provide a callback, as you're doing now, but in an async function, this only makes things more complicated.  You should **only** use the returned promise instead.  It will make your code easier to read.

Also, you should be calling `val()` at some point to convert a snapshot child into something that is actually a string.  I'll take a guess at when that should happen, but since you didn't provide your database structure, it's not possible to know for sure.

```
const snapshot = await ref.once('value');
const urls = [];
snapshot.forEach(urlSnapshot => {
    urls.push(urlSnapshot.val());
});
this.setState({ items: urls });
```

Comment: Does the callback already work similar to an await thus not requiring the need for a follow up async? What is the difference between using .val() and not using it at all if my return gives me a single value, in this case a url. Will it cause a typeError somewhere depending on how I want to use it?

Comment: You can think of await as automatically putting all the rest of the code in the function into a callback that is just not nested inside a function.  It only reason for existing is to make code that uses promises easier to read and write.